# ZIndex for one canvas over an adjacent canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to render a row of interlocking arrows, like this:

[image]

Each arrow represents a step in a workflow, and the color of each arrow is determined by its step's position in the workflow. While the example above has 3 colors (before, current, after), so far I've implemented only 2 colors (before/current, after) and that's fine for the purposes of this question. I've got an `IMultiValueConverter` to handle those colors.

The workflow steps are represented as a `StepStruct` which has a `Step` property (set manually, more on this later), and a `VmFunc` property which returns the view model for that step. My current `IMultiValueConverter` uses the index of the step in the list of steps, rather than the actual `Step` value.

My problem is the arrows. Initially I have each step as a canvas rendering a simple rectangle, and that's easy to get working. But to make the arrow, I've used a `PolyLine` that I want to position at the right of the canvas, indeed starting at the right of one canvas and overflowing into the next.

I can't get the `Panel.ZIndex` to work in such a way that a canvas's arrow is visible overflowing into its right-hand neighbor.

My code is pasted below. Of note:

- I've bound the `Polyline`'s `Panel.Zindex` (which I've read affects its parent canvas's z-index) to the `StepStruct`'s `Step` property, and I've set the `Step` values so that each step's value is *less than* the value of the step to its left, which should show left steps *over* the right step.
- I've commented a line setting the `Canvas.Left` property of each `PolyLine`. When I uncomment this line (and move it into place), the `Polyline` indeed moves over to the right side of the canvas, but it's invisible, which I imagine is because it's hidden behind the canvas to its right. (I've confirmed this by changing the `PolyLine` to start with negative x-values, so you can see the part that's not blocked by the neighboring canvas. This is not pictured.)
- I've rendered each canvas's `Step` as text, and those `TextBlock`s all have an identical z-index (40) so that they're in front of some `PolyLine`s and behind others, which shows that the `PolyLine` does have its z-index set right, at least within its own canvas.

```xml
<Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BackgroundBlack}" BorderThickness="2">

    <!--Progress bar-->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StepViewModels}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="progressBar">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas Height="24">
                    <Canvas.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Canvas">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundDarkGrey}"/>

                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <!-- the binding. this part works so I'm omitting the code -->
                                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <DataTrigger.Value>True</DataTrigger.Value>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledGrey}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Canvas.Style>

                    <Polyline Points="0,-1 20,11 0,25" Stroke="{StaticResource BackgroundBlack}" StrokeThickness="2" 
                            Fill="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}"
                            Panel.ZIndex="{Binding Step}"
                            />
                    <!--Canvas.Left="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}"-->

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Step}" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" Panel.ZIndex="40" Foreground="Pink" FontSize="20" Canvas.Left="8"/>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

The result (with the `Canvas.Left` still commented)
[image]

**How do I get the arrows to render at the end of one canvas and atop the next, as desired?**

(I could of course keep it this way and make it work but the bindings would be very annoying and complicated, needing to bind each arrow to the color of the *previous* canvas; or rather do some kind of conversion involving `IndexOf - 1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ZIndex:

Each item is wrapped by a ContentPresenter, this is done by the ItemContainerGenerator inside this ItemsControl instance.

So you need to edit the container to get a new ZIndex(via a ContentPresenter style and a binding for example).

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding XXX}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

For the shape:

I would recommend using a Path control with a predefined shape geometry like:

"M 0,0 L30,0 L34,5 L30,10 L0,10 z"

and have a negative margin at the end like Margin="0,0,-4,0"

Comment: Thanks. Good call on the negative margin, I hadn’t though of that. Could you post an example of editing the container as you mention?

Comment: Edited in an example.

Comment: Thank you, that z-index solution works perfectly! I'm still using the polyline I had before. Why do you prefer the path/margin solution you suggested?

Comment: Just a way to keep one coherent shape control and not a combintaion of a couple. Not that it's bad, just easier if you want to paint them the same color for fill/stroke, or do something with them.